# sReto iOS Swift 5.0

Tags: ios, swift

Hey guys so looking for a little help updating code from a GitHub library found here:

https://github.com/ls1intum/sReto

It appears the library has been updated up to Swift 4 however my project is currently running Swift 5

The project compiles and builds however crashes when I broadcast the first device

The crash is happening here on a file generated by cocoapod install:

```
public struct UUID: Comparable, Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
    /** Stores the UUID as a 16 byte array */
    let uuid: [UInt8]
    public var hashValue: Int { // CAUTION HERE
        return uuid.map { $0.hashValue }.enumerated().reduce(0,
            {
                let (index, hash) = $1
                return $0 ^ (hash << index * 2) // CRASH HERE
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Caution on 'hashValue': 'Hashable.hashValue' is deprecated as a protocol requirement; conform type 'UUID' to 'Hashable' by implementing 'hash(into:)' instead

Terminating exception on 'return line': Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Does anybody know where I can find a swift 5 link to the Reto library?

Should I ditch the Reto library and learn to use Bonjour on my own?

Or can someone explain what is happening here and how I can implement the 'hash(into:)'?

The only thing printing to console on crash is green '(lldb)'

I appreciate the help and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you found an answer yet, but I had the same problem and googled a bit. Turns out the hashable calculation is deprecated and automated now, so removing the whole

```
public var hashValue: Int { // CAUTION HERE
    return uuid.map { $0.hashValue }.enumerated().reduce(0,
        {
            let (index, hash) = $1
            return $0 ^ (hash << index * 2) // CRASH HERE
        }
    )
}
```

fixed the problem and resulted in working code!

Comment: I had actually decided to proceed with MultiPeer Connectivity and it seems to do the job well. I'm a bit hesitant to use a library that isn't being supported. I will be testing this week with 4 devices. I'll keep this in mind if I need an alternative. Thanks for the info!